# how to stop python from closing immediately

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having troubles with python every time I try to open my .py file it auto closes within like half a second and I was wondering how I can fix this issue. I've seen a lot of "just add an input and than the thing will stay open until you hit enter." but my code already has input variables and it still closes?

here is my code:

```
import random
answers = ['It is certain', 'It is decidedly so', 'Without a doubt', 'Yes – definitely', 'You may rely on it', 'As I see it, yes', 'Most likely', 'Outlook is good', 'yes', 'Signs point to yes', 'Reply hazy try again', 'Ask again later', 'Better not tell you now', 'Cannot predict now', 'Concentrate and ask again', 'Dont count on it', 'My reply is no', 'My sources say no', 'Outlook not so good', 'Very doubtful']

print('''
          __  __          _____ _____ _____    ___    ____           __      __        __
         |  \/  |   /\   / ____|_   _/ ____|  / _ \  |    |   /\    |  |    |  |      |  |
         | \  / |  /  \ | |  __  | || |      | (_) | | || /  /  \   |  |    |  |      |  |
         | |\/| | / /\ \| | |_ | | || |       > _ <  |    \ / /\ \  |  |    |  |      |__|
         | |  | |/ ____ \ |__| |_| || |____  | (_) | | || |/ ___  \ |  |___ |  |___    __
         |_|  |_/_/    \_\_____|_____\_____|  \___/  |____/_/    \_\|______||______|  |__|
         
         
         
                                                                                            ''')

print('Hello World, I am the Magic 8 Ball an omnipotent being, What is your name?')
name = input()
print('hello ' + name)


def Magic8Ball():
    print('Ask me a question.')
    input()
    print (answers[random.randint(0, len(answers)-1)] )
    print('I hope that helped!')
    Replay()
    

def Replay():
    print ('Do you have another question? Type Y if yes, and quit if you want to quit ')
    reply = input()
    if reply == 'Y':
        Magic8Ball()
    elif reply == 'quit':
        print('Goodbye ' + name)
        exit()
    else:
        print('I apologies, I did not catch that. Please repeat.')
        Replay()

        
Magic8Ball()

input()
```

Comment: Instead of double-clicking it, try running it from the command-line.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your code works perfectly intended as you written. In other words, it won't close until you type `quit`. Although, if you want to hang the terminal after you enter the `quit`, then you need to add `input()` before the `exit()` statement. If you meant other thing, please specify what exactly you mean.